# Expect script reads from file and puts everything on the same line

Tags: expect

Expect script should read commands from file and send them line by line through telnet, but it puts everything on the same line

I have file with commands and my task is to connect to telnet, read command from file and send it. I have to do it for all commands in file. I prepared script, but it puts all commands on the same line and send them as one.

Here is content of file with commands (those are just test commands)

```
add chain=forward src-address=1.1.1.1 action=log;
add chain=forward src-address=1.1.1.1 action=log;
add chain=forward src-address=1.1.1.1 action=log;
add chain=forward src-address=2.2.2.2 action=log;
add chain=forward src-address=2.2.2.2 action=log;
add chain=forward src-address=2.2.2.2 action=log;
add chain=forward src-address=2.2.2.2 action=log;
add chain=forward src-address=2.2.2.2 action=log;
add chain=forward src-address=3.3.3.3 action=log;
add chain=forward src-address=3.3.3.3 action=log;
add chain=forward src-address=3.3.3.3 action=log;
```

and here is script I am using

```
set timeout 1
set fid [open /home/toor/file.txt]
set content [read $fid]
close $fid

###
start telnet and login
###

set records [split $content "\r"]

foreach record $records {
   lassign $records \
         commands
   expect "> "
   send  "$commands\r"
}
sleep 1
expect "> "
send "quit\r"
```

Any advice, which help me to send every command separately would really help me and I will be very grateful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commands file probably has `\n` line endings not `\r`

```
set fid [open /home/toor/file.txt]
set records [split [read -nonewline $fid] "\n"]
# ..........................................^
close $fid
```

Your lassign command has no purpose. You can just `send "$record\r"`